# Same Address passed during method chaining in C++ for tree data structure?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I came across a Tree implementation online and had a confusion about the remove function of the implementation. Everything else is clear, apart from the idea of method chaining.

From my understanding the *this keyword returns the address of the object created and is unique to each object. So if i do something like this in the main function. Since i have created a single object, every time "this" keyword is used,it would have the same address.

```
    Bst newTree; //some random address associated with 
    newTree.remove(10).remove(20).remove(30);
```

This is a portion of the code but shows how the "this" keyword is used

```
BST& remove(int val, BST* parent =NULL){
   if(val < value){
     if(left != NULL)
       {
         left->remove(val,this)
       }
    }

  //some more code to deal with greater and lower values 
  return *this;
}
```

I guess my confusion is that in the recursive calls, we are giving the "this" address which is the same address because only one instance of that class has been created. So how does one call of the remove function defer from the other?

Comment: the keyword is `this` and `*this` is `this` dereferenced, ie the method does not return a pointer/address

Comment: btw "only one instance of that class has been created." in your code not a single instance is created. Would be good if you could present a [mcve]

Comment: `Tree` vs `BST` ... are those two supposed to be the same?

Comment: `newTree.remove(10)` returns a reference to `newTree`. The recursion inside `remove` has nothing to do with the chaining, and `this` will be different in every node of the tree.

Comment: @molbdnilo i guess thats my confusion, what is the effect of using this keyword inside the recursive call? and why will we have multiple values of this? since the object of the BST class has only be created once?

Comment: @MuneebRehman `this` works the same as any other variable (it's just a pointer to a `BST`), and recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. If the tree has any subtrees, those are also objects, and inside their member functions, `this` will point to that object.

Comment: so with each recursive call we have the "this" points to a new address? where is the new instance created for this new "this"? when i look at the following... remove(val, this) ... its seems like the same address is being sent over and over again... i guess i am expecting a explicit call to a new instance of the BST class to expect in the change of the address of this...

Answer (score 0):

`this` is just a pointer to "the current" object; it's a parameter that is passed to each member function "behind the scenes".

Let's rewrite this in a more "C-like" form, without classes and magic.

Here is a simplified tree:

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
```

and here is a `remove` that explicitly takes a pointer to the "current node" and returns it back to the caller:

```
Node* remove(Node* self, int val, Node* parent)
{
    if (val < self->value)
    {
        if (self->left != NULL)
        {
            remove(self->left, val, self);
        }
        // ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Note that the recursive invocation of `remove` gets this invocation's `self->left` as its `self` argument, and this invocation's `self` as its `parent`.
The result of the recursion is ignored; the function always returns its `self` argument untouched.

The way you would "chain" this function is by passing its result to the next function invocation:

```
Node *tree = ...;
remove(remove(remove(tree, 10), 20), 30);
```

The C++ class version works the same way.
The difference is that `this` is an implicit function parameter in that case, and returning a reference lets you use the normal member function call syntax, but the underlying mechanics are exactly the same.